# How to get first and Last Record from many interval values in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, range, intervals, min

I need to created a query for MSSQL to get only the first and the last record for each interval in a table on MSSQL. For example I have the following table

### id  |  label_id

1   |       A1

2   |       A2

3   |       A3

4   |       A4

5   |       A10

6   |    A11

7   |    A13

The result must to show something like

### label_id_start |   label_id_start  |  Count

```
A1         |       A4          |   4
A10        |       A11         |   2
A13        |       A13         |   1
```

I was looking for a solution but till now I could not find anything, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why `A1 | A2 | 1` doesn't count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such solution can be an option. But be aware that WITH construction has a limitation of recursion depth. Maximium recursion size can be increased by 200. `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 200)`

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (Iteration INT, Label VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @MyTable(Iteration, Label)
VALUES
    (1, 'A1'),
    (2, 'A2'),
    (3, 'A3'),
    (4, 'A4'),
    (5, 'A10'),
    (6, 'A11'),
    (7, 'A13')

DECLARE @RefinedTable TABLE (LabelId INT, Label VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @RefinedTable(LabelId, Label)
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(Label, 'A', '') AS INT) AS LabelNo, Label 
FROM @MyTable


DECLARE @Queue TABLE (Parent VARCHAR(50), Child VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @Queue(Parent, Child)
SELECT t1.Label, t2.Label
FROM @RefinedTable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN @RefinedTable t2
    ON t1.LabelId + 1 = t2.LabelId;

WITH Checker(Parent, Child, LastItem, Depth)
AS
(
    SELECT Parent, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(50)), Parent, 0  
    FROM @Queue
    WHERE Child IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT q.Parent, q.Child, c.LastItem, c.Depth + 1
    FROM @Queue q
    INNER JOIN Checker c
        ON c.Parent = q.Child 
)
SELECT 
    'A' + CAST(CAST(REPLACE(LastItem, 'A', '') AS INT) - MAX(Depth) AS VARCHAR) StartLabel,
    LastItem EndLabel,
    COUNT(*) AS [Count] 
FROM Checker
GROUP BY LastItem
ORDER BY 1
```